# How to make a multi-client server with synchronous dataread/write functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, boost-asio

Okay, so I *might* have got myself a big problem here. All this time, I've been basing my code in something I might *not* have wanted, that is, I'm using synchronous boost::asio functions with a server that can have multiple clients at the same time. Here it is:

```
void session(tcp::socket socket, std::vector<Player>* pl)
{
debug("New connection! Reading username...\n");

/* ...Username verification code removed... */

debug("Client logged in safely as ");
debug(u->name);
debug("\n");

for (;;)
{
    boost::array<unsigned char, 128> buf;

    size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

    if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        debug("Connection ended.\n");
        break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
    }
    else if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

    DataHeader ins = static_cast<DataHeader>(buf.data()[0]);

    std::vector<unsigned char> response;

    /* ... Get appropiate response... */

    // send response
    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(response), ignored_error);
    //debug("Sent ");
    //debug(response.size());
    //debug("B to client.\n");
}
}
```

As you can see from the code, I'm using `read_some` and `write` functions in a non-ideal scenario. Now, the question is, how did I make this code usable for multiple clients at the same time? Well, I used threads:

```
int main()
{
try
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

    debug("Ready.\n");
    for (;;)
    {
        std::thread(session, acceptor.accept(), &players).detach(); // Accept incoming clients
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Now, I've never had a problem with this setup until recently, that I started testing multiple clients at the same time on one server. This made the server crash many times, and just until now, I thought the problem were just connection issues. However, now I've started to wonder, "Might the problem be the synchronous functions?"

All the examples I've seen until now of multi-client servers use async functions, and maybe it's because *they are needed*. So, my final question is, do I *really* need async functions? Is there anything wrong with this code to make it crash? And finally, if async functions are needed, how could I implement them? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That endless loop spitting detached threads is wrong on multiple levels... And yes, you are definitely going to need to switch to async functions at some point (after you need to handle more than ~10 clients at the same time).

Comment: Why exactly? Are threads slow?

Comment: That loop basically keep spawning more and more threads until system fails to allocate new thread cause of resource exhaustion. And by detaching thread you basically forget about them.

Comment: Oh. Well, I don't just use threads just for convenience, I actually need to keep track of which thread belongs to which player. Is this possible to implement in async functions?

Comment: Depending on the number of clients you expect to be connected at the same time, a 1 to 1 relationship between player and thread is also sub optimal. What people usually do is have a thread pool and a nthreads : nplayers relationship, where nthreads < nplayers. I never used boost::asio, so I would not know if that option exists, there. The people who tried to talk me into boost::asio in the past always were scared of threads in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt) has pointed out, although this approach *may* work for a little bit, it's just better to switch to async functions due to resource exhaustion, so, I'll just redo the entire server to implement them.